# Adding 2 reactions to this?

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to add 2 reactions to this code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:JAX1:764860878512062505> offer'):
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} Has been offered by <:JAX1:764860878512062505>.')
    if message.content.startswith(f"{member.mention} Has been offered by <:JAX1:764860878512062505>"):
      emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='<:Accept:764926510673952859>')
      await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
```

But the issue is, is that the

```py
if message.content.startswith(f"{member.mention} Has been offered by <:JAX1:764860878512062505>"):
      emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='<:Accept:764926510673952859>')
      await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
```

Does not give me an error message, but also it does not add a reaction, someone please help me.

Comment: Do you have an error handler that could be suppressing error messages?

Comment: dont think so, because I'm using repl.it usually when something goes wrong tells me right away. Im not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`client.add_reaction` and `client.get_all_emojis()` is from an older version of discord.py.

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('<:JAX1:764860878512062505> offer'):
    member = message.mentions[0]
    msg = await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} Has been offered by <:JAX1:764860878512062505>.')
    await msg.add_reaction('<:Accept:764926510673952859>')
```

Comment: nope nothing still, https://gyazo.com/fb425949b947912e35e622c1ea2eb63c :/

Answer (score 0):

`client` has no attribute `add_reaction`. You should use `message.add_reaction`. So you can simply do `await message.add_reaction(emoji)` or `message.add_reaction('<:Accept:764926510673952859>')`.

Also, it's impossible to add a reaction in your code because at first, you are checking if the message content starts with `'<:JAX1:764860878512062505> offer'`, then if it is, you are trying to check if the same message content starts with `f"{member.mention} Has been offered by <:JAX1:764860878512062505>"`.

Comment: I get this error running it, `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: Are you using repl.it?

Comment: I don't know how to add reaction in repl.it but the logic of your code is wrong and I explained it, why are you using repl.it instead of rewrite?

Comment: I dont know, I use both but when resorting to more complex code I feel more comfortable using old discord.py instead of rewrite, also I got it to work I forgot to add the `await` in `message.add_reaction(emoji)`

Comment: Older versions of dpy are unlikely to work at this point, especially pre-rewrite (v1)